# $http service return nothing to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to get json result using $http callback, below is my service :

```
app.factory('topicContent', ['$http', function($http){

    var query = function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: 'http://daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
      });
    }

    return {
        request : function(){
            return query();
        }


    }
}]);
```

and within my controller I do like this

```
  topicContent.request().success(function(data){
    $scope.threadContent = data.data;
  });
```

But why my threadContent returned nothing?

Comment: Have you checked with the browser developer tools to check that the request is being sent correctly and what the response is?

Comment: @camden_kid it's 200 and I did saw my stuff in the callback, but wondering why it doesn't work when I used .success to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you don't need to read `data` property of the response object if you use `success` (you would have to in case of `then`). It should be:

```
topicContent.request().success(function(data){
    $scope.threadContent = data;
});
```

Comment: I tried     console.log($scope.threadContent);
but the console is not appearing.

Comment: Because this service doesn't implement JSONP. Are you sure it supports it?

Comment: This tutorial : http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-services.html used it and it worked.

Comment: When you open `http://daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` responce JSON must be wrapped with callback function. Plus content type is not correct, it should be `text/javascript`. Main problem is that `http://daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php` JSONP service.

Comment: I don't get it, what is the solution?

Comment: The solution is to use GET parameter `callback` and response with something like `echo $_GET['callback'] . ' ('. json_encode($data) . ')'`. So that the data object is wrapped with function call.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, your URL doesn't return `JSON`.

The Content-Type is `text/html`, it should be `application/json` instead.

Try switching your URL with any other JSONP supported URLs like below and it would work.

```
https://api.github.com/gists
```

If you look at Chrome developer tools console you can see the message.

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

You need to configure the server to send a JavaScript response with

```
Content-Type: application/javascript or application/json
```

Comment: echo with json_encode doesn't mean it will become json format?

Comment: if not using jsonp it will work. Now I confused btw json and jsonp.

Comment: I don't think so, you need to configure the server response to application/json or application/javascript.

Comment: That might work, but having said that I've a limited knowledge of PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
public function getData()
{
    header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
    // or try header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $data = array();
    echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($data) . ")";
    // or try $_GET["url"]["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($data) . ")";
}
```

JavaScript

```
var url = ".../getData?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
});
```

This is a good piece about AngularJS and AJAX with details about AngularJS and JSONP http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html

Comment: I got this error in php : Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: @Alexwood Are you using CakePHP by any chance? If so, try $this->header("Content-Type: text/javascript"); and $this->["url"]["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($data) . ")";